spring-security-rsa removed from spring -cloud-starter
Today I just uplifted spring cloud from 2023.x to 2024.0.0 and I can see the application build failed with the error. It seems spring-security-rsa is removed from spring-cloud-starter and it's not getting resolved in my pom. Adding the version in the pom works. Is this the correct behavior? IIRC this dependency is necessary for encrypt/decrypt of keys.

No, the functionality was moved to spring security and that dependency is no longer needed
